# Why the IBOutlet label disappears when I push back again to the VC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got a NavigationController to control my VCs.
VCA is the rootViewController.
VCB is a viewController with a tableView.
CustomCell is a custom class i inherit from UITableViewCell with a xib file built in and VCB inits the cells using delegate function with CustomCell and the class AFNetworking as followed:

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",testPath,urlString];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager POST:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        dataList=responseObject;
        NSLog(@"af get data");
        NSLog(@"%@",[[dataList objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"age"]);
        [self.tableViewList reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
    }];

}
return self;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"RecommendTableCellIdentifier";
static BOOL nibsRegistered = NO;
if (!nibsRegistered) {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"RecommendTableCell" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    nibsRegistered = YES;
}
RecommendTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[RecommendTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
dataRow=[dataList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.children=[dataRow objectForKey:@"children"];
if (cell.childrenLabel) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}else{
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
NSLog(@"cell get data:");
NSLog(@"%@",[dataRow objectForKey:@"age"]);
[cell addContent:dataRow];
[cell.wantToSeeButton setTag:[indexPath row]];
[cell.wantToSeeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iWantToSeeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cell;
```

}

The CustomCell xib has lots of IBOutlet labels.

The problem is:
When i push into VCB, the cell data appears normally.Then i pop back to VCA and then push into VCB again, this time, the cell data appears nothing.
As you see, i have lots of NSLog checks above in the code,all checks log the right thing BUT the cell.childrenLabel logs NO. It seems the second time i push into VCB, the IBOutlet childrenLabel is not inited.
What is the problem and how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you set the labels as `(strong)` elements? Maybe they are being released after you pop to VCA.

Comment: @BrunoPhilipe, the labels don't have to be strong. An IBOutlet to a UI element is usually weak, because its superview has a strong pointer to it. Anyway it's irrelevant because the whole controller is usually deallocated when you pop it off the stack.

Comment: How are you creating VCB in VCA? Are you using a storyboard or xib for your controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have made your `nibsRegistered` variable static.

Once you set that variable to YES, it will remain YES for the life of the program. When you go back to your view for a second time, it thinks it's already been registered.

You can either add a property and use that instead, like:

```
self.nibsRegistered = YES;
```

Or, more naturally, execute the registration code in your viewDidLoad method (which will only run once per view controller instance).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"RecommendTableCell" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```